# How to check if there are double letters in a 4 digit code in Java

Tags: java, string, input, char, double

The above question might seems vague but it's actually a very simple idea which i can't seem to figure out.

It basically is a 4 digit letter code containing letters from A to F for example: `ABDF`, `BAAF`, `DBAF` etc.

Now I'm trying to do some post input-handling where it must become impossible to enter a letter that is already in the code cause it has to be a unique 4 digit code with no repeating letter. I've been trying to make it work but none of my code seems to work so i'm back to scratch asking you guys for help :)

I hope this is somewhat clear otherwise i'll be happy to clear it up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code, and we might be able to help you. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @chancea i'm not sure if i understand that to the fullest, What i basicly try to make is a method that checks is the user is not typing in a code with a double letter somewhere

Comment: @chancea will do that right now i've been trying other solutions out too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean hasDuplicateChars(String string) {
    Set<Character> chars = new HashSet<Character>();
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
        if (!chars.add(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a collection that contains no duplicate elements. We will use [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-) method which returns true if this set did not already contain the specified element.

`hasDuplicateChars` functions iterates over characters in the input string using [toCharArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) function and for loop; each character is added to the `chars` set which is initially empty. If `add` method returns false it means that we have already encountered same character before. So we return false from our function.

Otherwise input is valid and method returns true.

Comment: The code looks like something i could use though i don't understand it could you explain it maybe?

Comment: @Rusty I have added some more details

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a pseudocode but it would work.

```
String uniquePass="";
while(uniquePass.length<4){
    String userInput=getUserInputChar()
    if(uniquePass.contains(userInput))
      rejectInputAndNotifyUser
        else
      uniquePass=uniquePass+userInput
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually meets the OP's requirements of **input handling** where all other answers are post-validation

Comment: @chancea I think you're right therefore i'll edit my post in the post-validation cause this isn't precisely what i need i'm sorry i made you go through the effort

Answer (score 0):

using this function you'll be able to see if the string contains unique characters

```
public static boolean checkForUnique(String str){
    boolean containsUnique = false;

    for(char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if(str.indexOf(c) == str.lastIndexOf(c)){
            containsUnique = true;
        } else {
            containsUnique = false;
        }
    }

    return containsUnique;
}
```

Update:

This will be ran everytime a user enters a character and if it fails, this would mean there is a duplicate. You have the choice of discarding that input or showing an error.

Comment: but as the user is typing you use this function to see if the input character is valid and if not, you don't save it or input an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you're validating the complete input, you can lean on the set semantics, and a few tricks

```
    String s = "ABAF";
    int count = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split(""))).size();
    if (count - 1 == 4) {
        System.out.println("All ok");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Repeated letters");
    }
```

the `split("")` will split the string to a an array like `{"","A", "B", "A", "F"}`.

The `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.split("")))` will create a Set with String elements, and as the Set will bounce back the elements already contained, the size of the set for e.g. "AAAF" will be 3 (it'll contain the "", "A" and "F"). This way you can use the size of the set to figure out if all letters of a String are unique

If its while typing you'll than the solution depends on the input method, but you can have something like (pseudo stuff)

```
if (pass.contains(letter)) {
  breakAndNotifyUser();
} else {
  pass+=letter;
}
```

Comment: i'm probably clumsy but i can't seem to get this to work if i run it with ABAF it will give me repeated letters back but if i do it with ABDF it will give me repeated letter none the less could you maybe elaborate it further?

Comment: I've explained further, the code should work for both cases its simple in its nature, if it keeps confusing you can post it in the question